# copy text from terminal to memory

Tags: c, linux, console, terminal

I know it will appear ugly, but, suppose a simple program like:

```
int main(void)
{
   int line=0, column=1;
   char c;
   system("clear");
   printf("0123\n4567\n");

   getprintedchar(column, line, &c);
   printf("%c", c);
   return 0;
}
```

That will print number `1`.

How can we program such function using LINUX terminal. I know we can use `ncurses`, but that prevent a lot of options `printf` and alike allows.

I wonder if we can use `struct termios` or some other super-clunk hacker!

For those comming from borland/windows, it resembles a simplified version of the `conio.h` function `gettext()`.

Can we read some area of memory? Maybe some `assembly` to get the character directly from some area of the `Video RAM`?

Thanks!

Comment: In the good old days all you had to do was read address 0xB8000.. That's not possible in a console, unless on a VM such as NTVDM, don't know if there's an equivalent for Linux.

Comment: Not having an answer hacking the problem, I'll accept the answer that states it is impossible (until another solution appears)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know we can use ncurses, but that prevent a lot of options printf and alike allows.

You can always use `snprintf` to format a string, then output it any way you want. (N)curses is a good library for terminal handling.

> Can we read some area of memory?

In particular, this is impossible. You can't access the terminal's memory since it's a separate process and it won't share.

Comment: I was thinking about that. I'll need the size columns x lines to calculate the size of the buffer, and treat all the code... Maybe overload printf...